# Saving thumbnail image along with video in Flutter/Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to save a thumbnail image from a video at the same time a video is saved to Cloud Firestore and I'm running into trouble. I can save the video to Storage and the url to a post in the Firestore database, but when I try to get the thumbnail I get a null error.

I've got a few async functions happening at once and I'm not able to get the variables I need set in order to use them for another function.

Here's the applicable code:

```
compressVideo() async {
    // compress video and assign path to mediaInfo
    MediaInfo? mediaInfo = await VideoCompress.compressVideo(
      file!.path,
      quality: VideoQuality.MediumQuality,
      deleteOrigin: false);
    // return the compressed file from the path
    final compressedVideoFile = mediaInfo!.file;
    setState(() {
      compressedFile = compressedVideoFile;
    });
  }

  getThumbnail(String mediaUrl) async {
    File? thumbnailImage = await VideoCompress.getFileThumbnail(mediaUrl);
    return thumbnailImage;
  }

  Future<String> uploadVideo(videoFile) async {
    UploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.child("post_$postId").putFile(videoFile);
    TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask;
    String downloadUrl = await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    return downloadUrl;
  }

  Future<String> uploadThumbnail(thumbnail) async {
    UploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.child("post_$postId").putFile(thumbnail);
    TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask;
    String thumb = await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    return thumb;
  }

  createPostInFirestore({ String mediaUrl="", String location="", String description="", String thumbnailUrl = "" }) {
    postsRef
      .doc(widget.currentUser!.id)
      .collection("userPosts")
      .doc(postId)
      .set({
        "postId": postId,
        "ownerId": widget.currentUser!.id,
        "username": widget.currentUser!.id,
        "mediaUrl": mediaUrl,
        "thumbnailUrl": thumbnailUrl,
        "description": description,
        "location": location,
        "timestamp": timestamp,
        "likes": {},
      });
  }

  handleSubmit() async {
    setState(() {
      isUploading = true;
    });
    buildLoading(context);
    await compressVideo();
    String mediaUrl = await uploadVideo(compressedFile);
    String thumbfile = await getThumbnail(await uploadVideo(compressedFile));
    String thumbnailUrl = await uploadThumbnail(thumbfile);
    createPostInFirestore(
      mediaUrl: mediaUrl,
      thumbnailUrl: thumbnailUrl,
      location: locationController.text,
      description: captionController.text,
    );
    captionController.clear();
    locationController.clear();
    setState(() {
      file = null;
      compressedFile = null;
      thumb = null;
      isUploading = false;
      postId = const Uuid().v4();
    });
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }
```

When I run the code above, I get the following error `_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)` which happens at the line `File? thumbnailImage = await VideoCompress.getFileThumbnail(mediaUrl);`

I'd appreciate if anyone can point me in the right direction. I've tried using plugins like video_thumbnail, which generates a thumbnail to display on screen, but it's slow when you have several videos on a screen and very data heavy. So I'm trying to store a thumbnail image in the database instead.

Comment: Does my posted answer help ? If yes then acknowledge it, if not then we can solve it further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with following line :

```
getThumbnail(String mediaUrl) async {
    File? thumbnailImage = await VideoCompress.getFileThumbnail(mediaUrl);
    return thumbnailImage;
  }
```

As per the [**getFileThumbnail method**](https://pub.dev/documentation/video_compress/latest/video_compress/Compress/getFileThumbnail.html)
This function returns File but you are Getting it in String

```
String thumbfile = await getThumbnail(await uploadVideo(compressedFile));
```

Here’s the changed Updated Code :

```
getThumbnail(String videoPath) async {
  final thumbnailPath = await VideoCompress.getFileThumbnail(videoPath);
  return File(thumbnailPath);
}

handleSubmit() async {
  setState(() {
    isUploading = true;
  });
  buildLoading(context);
  await compressVideo();
  String mediaUrl = await uploadVideo(compressedFile);
  File thumbnailFile = await getThumbnail(compressedFile!.path);
  String thumbnailUrl = await uploadThumbnail(thumbnailFile);
  createPostInFirestore(
    mediaUrl: mediaUrl,
    thumbnailUrl: thumbnailUrl,
    location: locationController.text,
    description: captionController.text,
  );
// …
}
```

You can also solve this problem with declaring a `File? thumbnail;` state and update in `generateThumbnail()` method so you can directly access the  `handleSubmit()` function.

Reference : [**video_compress**](https://pub.dev/packages/video_compress)

Comment: Thank you! Changing to a File type and saving the thumbnail in state solved the issue.